# Screen capture without active window using magnification for Windows 7 and Windows 8 in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

For Screen capture without active window ,
To achieve this, I Used magnification.dll. But Magnification is not working while DWM is enabled. can you please give the solution for this.

Even WinForm itself If I Set Transparency key and DWM is disabled, Then only its working.. ie is not working on Windows 7 & and Windows 8

Without using Transprency, How can i achieve this.

Lots of Thanks.....